# Use of unresolved identifier PFImageView

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I cannot seem to declare my imageView as PFImageView.
Keeps saying `Use of undeclared type 'PFImageView'`

[image]

- In storyboard, I changed the class to PFImageView
- I have imported the frameworks in the bridge file

One suggestion on the Parse forum says to do this, but not sure how to with swift:

```
//In AppDelegate / applicationDidLaunch add:

[PFImageView class];
```

#### Update:

After searching through the parse framework, I don't actually PFImageView in it.

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFImageView.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those of you still having trouble with this, I actually had to redownload the SDK and import an additional framework `ParseUI`

Then import into bridger:

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Time flies and if right now on the latest Parse version, if you are using cocoaPods, add pod `'Parse/UI`' to your **Podfile** and update.

Then you can use PFImageView again.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just add this to your class:

```
import ParseUI
```